# Antlr lexer match only when next character isn't a bracket

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to write a lexer rule that will match a variable name as follows.

```
TYPE: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_];
```

However, I also have a parser rule similar to below.

```
dup: TYPE 'x{' TYPE '}'
```

These easily match,

```
HELLO x{wee}
catx x{text}
```

but I want to be able to match the following as well.

```
HELLOx{wee}
namex{text}
```

Where x{ would match the token in the parser rule. The problem is that x is getting put into the TYPE token so the parser doesn't know what to do with the random {.

Is there anyway to get the lexer to not match a trailing x if it is followed by a {?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved with a lookahead, e.g.

```
dup
  : TYPE 'x{' TYPE '}'
  ; 

TYPE
  : [a-zA-Z]([a-wy-zA-Z0-9_]|('x' {_input.LA(1) != '{'}?))*
  ;
```

The definition of `TYPE` allows `x` only if the lookahead is not a `{`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought this was possible, I just didn't know the syntax for lookahead.